# Javascript. Как узнать сколько лет прошло с указанной даты до сегодняшнего дня?

Tags: javascript, html

Дату я беру с html :

```
        <input type="date" id="form_data" name="calendar">
```

Как узнать сколько целых лет прошло до сегодняшнего дня?

Answer (score 2):

1. Берем данные из Html
2. Создаем объекты типа Date для значения с html(пусть будет DataIn)
3. Создает Data для сегодня(пусть будет DataToday)
4. далее mbNotWholeYear = DataToday.year - DataIn.year (мы получили просто годы включительно, но возможно не целые)
5. Дальше делаем сравнением DataToday.month и DataToday.day с DataIn.month и DataIn.day
6. Если у DataToday эти значения больше или равно, чем у DataIn(тобишь прошло mbNotWholeYear и чуть больше) , значит WholeYear = mbNotWholeYear, иначе WholeYear = mbNotWholeYear - 1

P.S. На ресурсе в вопросах бывает много ответов. Для того, чтобы другие могли разобраться, что помогло автору, ответ отмечают галкой(тобишь ответ принял человек), тем самым давая понять, что помогло.

Comment: спасибо, но я не настолько умный в javascript , что бы понять ваши мысли, читая этот ответ

Comment: var date = dataln(); 
 
 
var dt = new Date();
// Display the month, day, and year. getMonth() returns a 0-based number.
var month = dt.getMonth()+1;
var day = dt.getDate();
var year = dt.getFullYear();
document.write(month + '-' + day + '-' + year);
// Output: current month, day, year
 
 
пока что это все что я понял

Comment: @Vladyslav я расписал алгоритм того, что нужно написать.